# Quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying for hours to fix this code, I can't see what's wrong:

```
document.getElementById('detail'+num).innerHTML='<a class="dobpicker" href="javascript:NewCal('+s_d+','+ddmmyy+')">'
```

The problem is in href="javascript ..."
s_d is a javascript variable defined as

```
var num = 2;
var s_d = "sname"+num;
var ddmmyy = "ddmmyy";
```

Basically I need to call a javascript function with different parameter each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a backslash like `\'`.

```
document.getElementById('detail'+num).innerHTML=
 '<a class="dobpicker" href="javascript:NewCal(\''+s_d+'\',\''+ddmmyy+'\')">'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the value of a `href` attribute, HTML encode them:

```
document.getElementById('detail'+num).innerHTML='<a class="dobpicker" href="javascript:NewCal(&quot;'+s_d+'&quot;,&quot;'+ddmmyy+'&quot;)">'
```

Or better yet don't use the `javascript:` protocol:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(num) {
    var s_r = "sname"+num;
    var ddmmyy = "ddmmyy";
    var aEl = document.createElement("a");
    aEl.className = "dobpicker";
    aEl.onclick = function() {
        NewCal(s_d, ddmmyy);
    }
    document.getElementById('detail'+num).appendChild(aEl);
});
```

Comment: I would guess this is only being done once on page load, but if not you'd also need to remove the previous anchor element when appending a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.innerHTML` setting is using `s_d`, but your variable declaration has `s_r`.

EDIT: That was the first thing that jumped out at me. Having looked a bit closer and realised the values are strings, I think fixing the variable name together with adding some escaped quotation marks as in Daniel A. White's answer will do the trick.